# How to disable IP showing in Google Cloud DNS

Tags: google-cloud-dns

Im using Google Cloud DNS and I want to disable IP showing when someone is ping my domain.

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you please provide more details about your use case? Do you need internal (private) DNS?

Comment: 1) That is not possible. 2) DNS is a public database. 3) If you could do this, your domain would not work. 4) If you do not want ping (ICMP) to work, block that protocol in your firewall.

Comment: cloudflare provides this: https://youtu.be/LlbTSfc4biw?t=1179

Comment: Cloud Flare uses a load balancer. Google also offers load balancers. Instead of your instance needing a public IP address, your domain uses the IP address of the load balancer. No matter what you configure, no matter which service, the end result is a domain name translates to an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of beats the purpose of DNS. Isn’t it?
You want to disable the resolving of the DNS address to the actual IP? Just avoid using DNS all together!

Maybe you want to explain the actual use case?

There are many techniques for protecting your external IP but we must understand the use case. An example will be to use a proxy that the DNS will resolve to and which will redirect the traffic to the actual desired server

You can how ever block specific protocols if you wish to block ping for example - block the ICMP protocol on your firewall.

Comment: Is there any way to create reverse proxy on google cloud?

Comment: Google it :  https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/target-proxies, https://auth0.com/docs/custom-domains/configure-custom-domains-with-self-managed-certificates/configure-gcp-as-reverse-proxy, https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-vs-load-balancer/